# check if canvas pixel is of a given color

Tags: javascript

A canvas has CSS `background-color: #D3D3D3;` and one property `ctx.fillStyle = "#000";`.
This JS code needs to leave the stroke intact and make every thing else transparent background. How can this be achieved?

```
imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;

let clearBack = imageData;
for (var i = 3; i < clearBack.length; i += 4) {
  if (pixle is not black) { //if pixel belongs to the stroke leave it
    clearBack[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You can go through every 4 pixels (red green blue alpha) and check each color with the imageData. Then if its not black, do what you want with it.

You can use `putImageData` to rewrite any modified pixels back to the screen. Make sure you keep the original `ImageData` object in your `imageData` var though.

```
imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //take away the .data

var r, g, b, a;

for(var i = 0; i+3 < imageData.data.length; i+=4) {
    r = imageData.data[i];
    g = imageData.data[i+1];
    b = imageData.data[i+2];
    a = imageData.data[i+3];

    if((r > 0 || g > 0 || b > 0) && a > 0) { // if pixel is not black, and not transparent          
        imageData.data[i+3] = 0; //set alpha to 0
    }
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); //put the imageData back to the screen
```

Heres a fiddle. I was doing something slightly different there but you get the idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/q0n5sxku/

Comment: Isn't the data arranged such that the first pixel is referenced by the first 4 values, thus the forth value of the array is I+3 which is alpha? if so, why does you code says `a = imageData.data[i+4]` and not `[i+3]`? The reason for this question is that the if block is never entered.

Comment: My mistake thats a typo